# Cucumber error: Caused by: gherkin.lexer.LexingError: Lexing error on line 1

Tags: java, cucumber, lexical-analysis, gherkin

I have a cucumber feature file that goes in error when I run it and also Eclipse editor warning me with a error.

For me the syntax is correct.

```
@feature100
Feature: Feature-100: Category Navigation
Landing on homepage, it is possible to select a category through main navigation menu. Clicking on one of them, the Product grid page is reached.
Here all the filter types are listed in the bar: selecting one or more filter for filter type, the page refresh showing filter result in the grid. The number of filters selected updates near each filter type.
Once a filter is selected, Reset Filters functionality appears the left side of the bar.
Clicking on one of the products listed in filter result, the product detail page is reached. 

@test100 @active @screenshot @frontend @payment @caus
Scenario Outline: Feature-100 Group CAUS. 
Given FRONTEND_HOME_PAGE I access to homepage <Initials> and <Language>
And   FRONTEND_HOME_PAGE I control cookie alert <Initials> <Language>
And   FRONTEND_HOME_PAGE I click category GIFTS <Initials> and <Language>
And   FRONTEND_HOME_PAGE I click category FOR HER <Initials> and <Language>
And   FRONTEND_HOME_PAGE I select filters grid color
And   FRONTEND_HOME_PAGE I select filters grid material
#And   FRONTEND_HOME_PAGE I select filters grid line
#And   FRONTEND_HOME_PAGE I select filters grid gender
#And   FRONTEND_HOME_PAGE I select filters grid dimension
#And   FRONTEND_HOME_PAGE I select filters grid sort
#And   FRONTEND_HOME_PAGE I select filters grid all
#Then  FRONTEND_HOME_PAGE I select filters for product
@us
Examples: US Success
|Initials|Language|
| "us"   |"en"    |
```

If I run the cukes class I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Error parsing feature file C:/works/integrationtest/frontend/frontend.test/src/it/javatest/RunCukes100.java
    at cucumber.runtime.FeatureBuilder.parse(FeatureBuilder.java:133)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.loadFromFeaturePath(CucumberFeature.java:104)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.load(CucumberFeature.java:54)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.load(CucumberFeature.java:34)
    at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.cucumberFeatures(RuntimeOptions.java:235)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:110)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:36)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:18)
Caused by: gherkin.lexer.LexingError: Lexing error on line 1: 'package it.integrationtest.frontend.test;
```

and also Eclipse reports me an error:

[image]

Comment: It seems to complain about the stray `@us` tag. Have you tried putting it on the same line as the other tags instead of directly before your table?

Comment: i try, it seems that the problem is about @us tag

Comment: Please elaborate - does the error go away if you move the @us tag as I suggested? Or does it persist, and the only way to get rid of the error is to remove the tag completely?

Comment: if i cut the tag , the error move on @it thath is the following

Comment: There is no @it in your code. Please post the *real* code you're using and the *real* error message you get. Don't type it in manually - use copy&paste.

Comment: I've used that pattern, tagging various Examples: tables within one Scenario Outline:, done both in cucumber-jvm and ruby cucumber. I never had a lexing problem. Could it be something else, such as a hook for the @us tag?

Comment: i found thath the problem was the method that i run feaure. Now i try to run it like junit test, but it seems doesn't finf the feature file. i set program arguments  [code]--glue it.sopra.gucci.bdd.integrationtest.frontend.model.steps[code]  and vm arguments: [code]-ea[code] and also set my working directory but result is 0 Scenarios
0 Steps
0m0,000s